# Vue Unit Tests: How to trigger select event on a v-radio in Vue + Vuetify + Jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue/Vuetify and I am trying to add some unit (with Jest) tests to my component.

In my UI, I have a radio button that when selected, displays a div.

The behavior is correct in a browser.

I need to simulate a click on that radio button:

```
<v-radio-group v-model="feedbackType">
    <v-radio value="value1" @change="changeType"></v-radio>
    <v-row v-if="value1Selected" class="ma-4"></v-row>
</v-radio-group>
```

Here is my test code:

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    mocks: { /* ... */},
    stubs: [ 'vRadio', /* ... */ ]
});

const radio = wrapper.find('[value=value1]');
radio.element.selected = true;
await radio.trigger('change');
// await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // This doesn't help
```

`radio.html()` after the trigger:

```
<vradio-stub value="value1"></vradio-stub>
```

and radio-group doesn't contain my `v-row`.

Does someone have any insight on how to test the v-radio click?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is vRadio stubbed? it seems it should be there so events can happen and then assert that the div appears when selected can happen. For basic radio element testing, an example can be read here https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/setchecked.html#setchecked

Comment: I had to stub vRadio to avoid the warning `Unknown custom element: <v-radio> - did you register the component correctly?`, but this is probably the root cause.
I looked at [vuetify unit-testing](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#bootstrapping-vuetify), but didn't manage to make it work.